# I am getting poor results on the confusion matrix but while training 99.44% accuracy on val_set on the last epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My Dataset has two folders, Test and Train. Test contains 2 folders inside with Covid X rays and Normal X rays and same is with the Train folder. I'm getting 99.4% accuracy on val_set on last epoch of training, but while plotting confusion matrix, I am getting not even 60% accuracy.

And also my Y_pred looks weird, and not between 0-1 certainty, I need help to get the same 99.4% results on my confusion matrix and classification report.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from keras.applications import xception
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *
from keras.preprocessing import image

model = xception.Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
for layers in model.layers:
    layers.trainable=False
    
flat1 = Flatten()(model.layers[-1].output)
class1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(flat1)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(class1)

model = Model(inputs = model.inputs, outputs = output)


model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


train_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    )

test_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Major/CovidDataset/Train',
    target_size = (224,224),
    batch_size = 10,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Major/CovidDataset/Test',
    target_size = (224,224),
    batch_size = 10,
    class_mode='binary')

#model Fitting

hist = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=validation_generator)



from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

Y_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps = np.ceil(validation_generator.samples / validation_generator.batch_size), verbose=1, workers=0)
y_pred = [np.where(predictions>0.5, 1, 0) for predictions in Y_pred]
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(validation_generator.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = ['Covid', 'Normal']
print(classification_report(validation_generator.classes, y_pred, target_names=target_names))

OUTPUT::

Epoch 1/2
255/255 [==============================] - 464s 2s/step - loss: 1.4076 - accuracy: 0.9342 - val_loss: 0.3753 - val_accuracy: 0.9718
Epoch 2/2
255/255 [==============================] - 558s 2s/step - loss: 0.1218 - accuracy: 0.9885 - val_loss: 0.0181 - val_accuracy: 0.9944
Confusion Matrix
[[310 100]
 [ 97  25]]
Classification Report
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

       Covid       0.76      0.76      0.76       410
      Normal       0.20      0.20      0.20       122

    accuracy                           0.63       532
   macro avg       0.48      0.48      0.48       532
weighted avg       0.63      0.63      0.63       532

Y_pred looks like:

1.05698e-14
2.25061e-13
3.96925e-19
5.53114e-17
3.4461e-32
1.2413e-32
2.29092e-28
4.01138e-17
3.81177e-23
1.88817e-07
1.164e-07
.
.
.
(532 Values)
```

Comment: This might be an issue of overfitting.The model might perform poorly in the validation set.

Comment: NO, i think this isnt an overfitting issue, because i wouldnt have got 99.44% accuracy then, also val_accuracy and train_accuracy are quite similar, So, definately not overfitting, something's wrong with my confusion matrix code and Y_pred

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't see the `val_accuracy` being printed

Comment: That's fine, could you please provide some help, if you know the solution?

Comment: Could you rerun with metrics = ['binary_accuracy', 'categorical_accuracy'] instead of just 'accuracy' ?

Comment: Yes, still giving 99.39% on binary accuracy

Comment: But, still same with confusion matrxi, i think theres a problem in my confusion matrix code, please help!

Comment: It might be because you're shuffling the validation set I've already mentioned about it yesterday. You replied: `My Y_pred looks very weird`, I also told that it was because sigmoid activation. Even if you did not understand, please do some research about the topic and then if you have a specific problem just post it. Posting something multiple times can get you banned from SO.

Comment: should i change "sigmoid" to "softmax" in the last dense layer?

Answer (score -1):

your problem is with

```
y_pred = [np.where(predictions>0.5, 1, 0) for predictions in Y_pred]
```

print this out and you will see it is a list of arrays because Y_pred is an array try

```
 y_pred=[ np.argmax(Y_pred[i]) for i in range(val_generator.samples)]
```

Comment: STILL NO LUCK, NOW GETTING 410(TP) and REST 122(FN)